# confused with cy.log in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

This is my code to print totals - length of elements product:

```
cy.fixture('searchProducts').then(function (arr) {
        let arrProducts = [];
        let totals ;
        let totalGetJson;
       
        arr.forEach(($product) => {
            if ($product.nameProduct == "dress") {
                arrProducts = $product;
                totalGetJson= $product.total
                productsPage.getProductList.as('listProduct')
            }
        });

        totals = cy.get('@listProduct').then(($elements) => {
            expect(totalGetJson).to.eq($elements.length)
            return $elements.length  
        })
        //print [object Object]aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        cy.log(totals +"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
        return totals
    })
    .then((totals) => {
        // print null
        cy.log(totals) 
        
    });
```

when I put cy.log(totals +"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") before return totals then cy.log(totals) in block then() is null

if I remove line cy.log(totals +"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") then cy.log(totals) in block then() is $elements.length is 9

I don't  understand the way work for Javascript in Cypress in sittuation

Please explain to me, I really know to understand, thank a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of your callback have some asynchronous commands inside, so you need to treat the return value asynchronously as well.

Here's three versions of similar code using Cypress `example.json` and public site example.com.

**Synchronous then() callback**

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com');
cy.fixture('example')
  .then(exampleData => {
    const name = exampleData.name  
    return name
  })
  .then(name => {
    expect(name).to.eq('Using fixtures to represent data')    // passes
  })
```

**Asynchronous then() callback**

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com');
cy.fixture('example')
  .then(exampleData => {

    let name

    // Dummy async call where result is set internally
    cy.get('h1').then(() => {
      name = exampleData.name  
    })
    
    return name     // returns too soon!!
  })
  .then(name => {
    expect(name).to.eq('Using fixtures to represent data')   // fails
  })
```

**Asynchronous then() callback with async result handling**

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com');
cy.fixture('example')
  .then(exampleData => {
    let name

    return cy.get('h1').then(() => {     // return this line so that test waits 
      return name = exampleData.name     // return internal data result
    })

  })
  .then(name => {
    expect(name).to.eq('Using fixtures to represent data')   // passes
  })
```

---

Comment: how does this answer the OP's question about getting the `null` result if adding a `cy.log` in between?

Comment: Perfect answer, illustrates the problem nicely!

Answer (score -1):

Assigning a cypress chain call into a variable is [a bad practice](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Assigning-Return-Values).
Cypress doesn't seem to support multiple 'active' commands. So when you add a `log` command in between, Cypress probably  invalidates your `totals` one and so you can't use it later.
You could use an alias to save the result of a command:

```js
cy.fixture('searchProducts').then(function (arr) {
        let arrProducts = [];
        let totals ;
        let totalGetJson;
       
        arr.forEach(($product) => {
            if ($product.nameProduct == "dress") {
                arrProducts = $product;
                totalGetJson= $product.total
                productsPage.getProductList.as('listProduct')
            }
        });

        totals = cy.get('@listProduct').then(($elements) => {
            expect(totalGetJson).to.eq($elements.length)
            return $elements.length  
        }).as('totals')
        //print [object Object]aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        cy.log(totals +"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
    })
    cy.get('@totals').then((totals) => {
        cy.log(totals) 
    });
```

I also found that the original example seems to work in Cypress 9 and does not work in Cypress 11.
Which version do you use?

Comment: I am using version 12